# "brew install git" fails trying to download manpages

Tags: git, homebrew, osx-snow-leopard, manpage

I'm attempting to install Git using Homebrew on OS X 10.6.8 running XCode 3.2.6 (the most up-to-date for Snow Leopard). When I run `brew install git`, I receive the following output:

```
==> Downloading https://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-1.9.0.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/git-1.9.0.tar.gz
==> make prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.9.0 sysconfdir=/usr/local/etc CC=gcc-4.2
==> make CC=gcc-4.2 CFLAGS= LDFLAGS=
==> make clean
==> make CC=gcc-4.2 CFLAGS= LDFLAGS=
==> Downloading http://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-manpages-1.9.0.tar.gz
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
Error: Failed to download resource "git--man"
Download failed: http://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-manpages-1.9.0.tar.gz
```

The url for the manpages works just fine in-browser, so I have directly downloaded the tarball with no issues. I'm guessing that if I can just stick the manpages into the right directory, Homebrew will see that they're there already and not try to `curl` the offending url. If it doesn't work, I suppose I have to start hacking at git.rb or the associated makefile?

Running `brew doctor` gives some warnings about libraries (which I'm pretty sure are unimportant here) as well as:

```
Warning: Some directories in /usr/local/share/man aren't writable.
This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed
by Homebrew. If a brew tries to add locale information to one of these
directories, then the install will fail during the link step.
You should probably `chown` them:

    /usr/local/share/man/de
    /usr/local/share/man/de/man1
You must: brew install git
```

**So the question:** Where should I place the manpages tarball to try to make Homebrew skip that download? If that doesn't work, what's the next best thing to attempt?

Comment: Have you run `brew update`? Homebrew currently ships git 2.3.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using the official git installer?

http://git-scm.com/download/mac

Comment: In the end, this is what it took. I was hoping to get a better handle on troubleshooting Hombrew, but alas, it's not to be.

Answer (score 0):

Run `brew update` before installing software to make sure that you're using the current versions of formulas. The current `git` formula has a working resource.

You could have staged your downloaded file as `/Library/Caches/Homebrew/git--man-1.9.0.tar.gz`.